# logstash mysql input plugin not running

Tags: mysql, input, logstash

I am running logstash 2.4.0
this is my config file

```
        input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/PATH/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://HOST:3306/test"
    jdbc_user => "te"
    jdbc_password => "te0"
    schedule => "5 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM test WHERE updated_at > :sql_last_value"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
  elasticsearch {
    host => "10.45.12.180:9200"
    index => "trst"
  }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> ./bin/logstash agent -f mysqllogstash.conf Settings: Default pipeline
>   workers: 16

```
Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :backtrace=>["/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:159:in `prepare_jdbc_connection'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-3.1.0/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:187:in `register'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:330:in `start_inputs'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:329:in `start_inputs'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:180:in `start_workers'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/home/ksugana/logstash-2.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.4.0-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:491:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
```

I have ran the `-configtest` but there are no config errors. debug does not give more information than this. I can connect to the database using mysql client from this host. 
Any help appreciated.

Running with logstash 2.3.2 I get this error.

Pipeline aborted due to error {:exception=>#

::ConfigurationError: Java::com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?>

Comment: Are you sure that `/PATH/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` exists?